# How to run series of SQL statements stored in a .text file in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I store such sqls in a text file:

```
insert into table ...;
...
insert into table ...;
```

How to executable all those statements with PHP? It seems `mysql_query()` can only execute 1 statement every time.

**UPDATE**

The reason I don't do it in command line like this

```
mysql -u your_user_name -p -D your_database_name < your_sql_file.txt;
```

is that it won't work when there's multi-byte characters in `your_sql_file.txt`, will get stuff like `æ¢µå¤©çœ¼`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$txt = file_get_contents('FILE.txt');
$queries = explode(';', $txt);
foreach($queries as $sql){
   mysql_query($sql)
}
```

Comment: What if the value contains semicolon?

Answer (score 0):

- open the file
- read each line
- use [`mysql_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)